# Using LINQ with Select and Distinct Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

If I use the following code in LINQPad to query my database I get the desired results:

```
LoadTables.Where(o=> o.Approver== "Name Name" ||o.Approver== "Name.Name").Select(o=>o.SubmittedBy).ToList().Distinct()
```

However, if I amend this and put it into my code, I get an error:

```
public IEnumerable<LoadTable> TableList;
TableList = _context.LoadTable.Where(o => o.Approver == GetADDetails.displayName || o.Approver == GetADDetails.userName).Select(o => o.SubmittedBy).ToList().Distinct();
```

The error returned is:

Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<App.Models.LoadTable>' An explicit conversion exists.`

Where am I going wrong?

For context, see previous quested here:

[Using LINQ to loop through data and display in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56233558/using-linq-to-loop-through-data-and-display-in-a-table)

Currently it's returing a new table for every match, I'm trying to get it to return a table per user.

Comment: You call a `Select(o => o.SubmittedBy)`, so you only return that string `SubmittedBy` and not a complete `LoadTable` object. Hence the returned sequence is a `IEnumerable<string>` and not a `IEnumerable<LoadTable>`.

Comment: The code `...Select(o=>o.SubmittedBy)` is creating an enumerable of strings. If you want an enumeration of `LoadTable` then you need something like `...Select(o=> new LoadTable{ SubmittedBy = o.SubmittedBy})`. Though it looks like you only want the strings. Do you know what the `Select` is doing?

Comment: remove `.Select(o => o.SubmittedBy)`

Comment: @asd to me it seems OP is rather looking for something like `DistinctBy()` (which probably isn't supported by the query provider).

Comment: @René Vogt exactly that, I'm currently getting a new table for every match, I only want a table for every unique username.

Comment: Added some extra info to try and explain further.

Comment: Why not just change `public IEnumerable<LoadTable> TableList;` to `public IEnumerable<string> TableList;`

Comment: Can you provide some data so we can run some tests?

Answer (score 0):

Remove from the Linq expresion `Select(o => o.SubmittedBy)` and put `Distinct()`before of `ToList()`:

```
public IEnumerable<LoadTable> TableList;
TableList = _context.LoadTable.Where(o => o.Approver == GetADDetails.displayName || 
  o.Approver == GetADDetails.userName).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: And what do you think `Distinct` is going to do here?

Comment: @DavidG When you make ToList(), EF materializes the query against BBDD. If you put `Distinct()` after `ToList()` you receive from database all the records, filtering them later with `Linq`.

Comment: Yes, but what do you think this will do given all fields being returned, including the primary key for the table? (*Hint: It's going to make no difference.*)

Comment: @DavidG Yes, you're right because it recovers all the fields. It's just a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting a string property

```
**.Select(o => o.SubmittedBy)**
```

this return `IEnumerable<string>`

you need something like below

```
_context.LoadTable.Where(o => o.Approver == GetADDetails.displayName || o.Approver == GetADDetails.userName).Distinct().GroupBy(p => p.SubmittedBy).Select(grp => grp.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Whist this does work, it will on return 1 result per SubmittedBy, I'm guessing from FirstOrDefault()?

Comment: yes it will return firstordefault of each record. say result is [1,1,1,2,2,3] it will return [1,2,3] this is just an example

Comment: So if I use FirstOrDefault(), how do I stop only the first result coming through on a child for loop? 
See my previous question for info
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56233558/using-linq-to-loop-through-data-and-display-in-a-table
Thanks!

Comment: doing so : _context.LoadTable.Where(o => o.Approver == GetADDetails.displayName || o.Approver == GetADDetails.userName).Distinct().GroupBy(p => p.SubmittedBy).Select(s => s); will return a list of LoadTable Single grouped by Submitted... is it what you need ?

Comment: @GabrielScavassa I believe so, but that throws a cannot convert type error. Possibly due to the way I've declared the list. I'm not sure how to get around that.

Answer (score 0):

Alas you forgot to tell us what kind of objects are in the sequence that is returned by `_context.LoadTable`. Looking at your code, it seems that it returns an enumerable sequence of objects, where every object has at least a property `SubmittedBy`.

Looking at your error, it seems that `SubmittedBy` is a string property.

If you had split your code into smaller pieces and used proper identifiers, you would soon have seen your problem.

Let's examine your code:

```
IEnumerable<LoadTable> TableList = _context.LoadTable
    .Where(o => o.Approver == GetADDetails.displayName || o.Approver == GetADDetails.userName)
    .Select(o => o.SubmittedBy)
    .ToList()
    .Distinct();
```

`_context.LoadTable` returns an IEnumerable sequence of items unknown by me, so let's assume it is a sequence of `Notes`:

```
IEnumerable<Note> notes = _context.LoadTable;
```

It could be that `LoadTable` returns an `IEnumerable` instead of `IEnumerabl<Note>`, in that case you should cast the loaded table.

The next statements:

```
IEnumerableM<Note> notesApprovedByUser = notes
    .Where(note => note.Approver == GetADDetails.displayName 
                || note.Approver == GetADDetails.userName);
IEnumerable<string> submitters = notesApprovedByUser
    .Select(note => note.SubmittedBy);
List<string> submitterList = submitters.ToList();
IEnumerable<string> distinctSubmitters = submitterList.Distinct();
```

It is easy to see that a sequence of strings can't easily be converted to a sequence of `LoadTables`.

The question is: do you want unique `LoadTables`, or do you want for every submitter all hist submitted notes? In that case you'll have to `Groupby` instead of `Select`:

```
.Where(note => ...)
.GroupBy(note => note.SubmittedBy,  // make groups of Notes submitted by the same submitter
   // parameter resultSelector: take every submitter and all notes that
   // were submitted by this submitter to make a new object
   (submittedBy, notesSubmittedByThisSubmitter) => new
   {
       // select the properties you plan to use
       Submitter = submittedBy
       LoadTables = notesSubmittedByThisSubmitter.Select(note => new LoadTable
       {
           ... again: select the properties you need
       })
       .ToList(),
   });
```

> Remember: keep an `IEnumerable<...>` an `IEnumerable<...> as long as possible. If not necessary, don't do a`ToList()`before you return. If your query returns 1000 items, and your caller will only do`FirstOrDefault`, or`Take(3).ToList()`, it would be a waste of processing power to create your complete list